# Excel - I need the output like this. I used Xlookup for 1st and 3rd columns(sales). I'm not sure hot to find the revenue ones

Tags: excel, vba

Original data:

| 2020/01/01 | 2020/01/01 Revenue | 2020/01/07 | 2020/01/07 Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 7855.6 | 354 | 8745.4 |

Output:

| Week | Sale | Revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020/01/01 | 500 | 7855.6 |
| 2020/01/07 | 354 | 8745.4 |

Comment: If you can find the sales then re-use index but change the result column.

Comment: They are true date or string as date formatted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The dates are formatted as General.

Comment: I've a large sales and revenue dataset of over 15 weeks. I've weeks in a separate column for weeks. I'm trying to solve just for 2 weeks on how to get them as the output. I'm able to do it manually using the offset function after transposing. But looking for a more efficient way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***Sale*** column-

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$2,MATCH(A7,$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

For ***Revenue*** column-

```
=INDEX($A$2:$D$2,MATCH(TEXT(A7,"yyyy/mm/dd") & " " & $C$6,$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Sale column works great but not the revenue column. My inputs headers are in "general" format.

Comment: If they are not date then try `=INDEX($A$2:$D$2,MATCH(A7 & " " & $C$6,$A$1:$D$1,0))`

Comment: It's still not working, sorry. I'm getting #NA

Comment: Can you show your formula? Put a screenshot of your data.